# Genus 2 drawing

Tags: general-topology, geometry

I am asked to draw a picture of a genus two using only polygons and then calculate the euler characteristic. I take it I'm aiming to use the least amount of polygons for the sake of the diagram but can't think how to do this in 3d.

Comment: What do you mean by "picture"?  Are you trying to draw a surface of genus two?  Have you drawn surfaces of genus one using polygons?

Comment: Well im just told to draw a picture of the double torus and then count F, E, and V to work out the euler characteristic. I've not drawn a genus 1 using polygons and there is nothing to do with it in my notes apart from defining the genus.

Comment: I take it it means the surface but have no idea how to draw it with polygons. Any tips?

Comment: Which textbook are you using? Massey spends a lot of space to describe construction of surfaces from polygons. Your textbook likely does the same.

Comment: Im using course notes rather than any text book. I think that the main part is to show that the euler characteristic is that of a double torus by knowing the number of faces edges and vertices but haven't had any experience drawing them. Are there any good online resources that anyone knows of for this?

Comment: Check Hatcher's book http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html, maybe he discusses this, I forgot. In general, it is a good idea to have a textbook in addition to class notes, which could be incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Consider reading chapter 1 of [this book](http://matematicas.uis.edu.co/~mruedapu/Libros/Libros/Topologia%20algebraica/Massey%20W.%20S.%20Basic%20course%20in%20algebraic%20topology%20%28Springer,%201991%29%28444s%29.pdf)  by William Massey (classification of surfaces using polygonal representation). I like this book a lot.